# Entering gmail credentials in Python

Tags: python, gmail

I want to hard code my credentials so that every time I run the script I don't need to enter them. I am attaching code

```
import email, getpass, imaplib, os, sys
user = input("Gmail username: ")
pwd = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
sender_email = input("Enter the sender's email (to filter by): ")
```

Comment: It is completely unclear what is your expectation from this question. What is the context that the code is to be used in, what is the surrounding code, what is the issue that you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't read the input assign it directly to the varaibale

```
ORG_EMAIL = "@gmail.com"

FROM_EMAIL = "username" + ORG_EMAIL

FROM_PWD = "XXXXXX"
```